# Added html form not submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am adding a form to my page on click action. The HTML initially lives in a script tag and is injected into the page. When I submit the form, nothing happens.

Over a decade of doing this I've not seen this behavior, but maybe there's something about this scenario I've missed.

```
<script type="text/html" id="modalcontent">
  <form id="myform" action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="whatever" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
</script>
```

Then in a jQuery click binding I have:

```
//modal shows up just fine
$(document).on("submit", "#myform", function(){
    console.log("Delegated!") <- never see this
});
document.getElementById("modal").innerHTML = document.getElementById("modalcontent").innerHTML;
console.log($("#myform")); //<- confirms form element exists
$("#myform").on('submit', function (ev) {
    console.log("MADE IT!!") //<- but I never see this
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
}, false);
```

So here I am, binding this submit directly to the form, not even delegating this submit to the document. But NOTHING happens. The `console.log` inside the callback doesn't fire, but neither does the form submit naturally. So I'm lead to believe it's my HTML, or for some reason the browser doesn't like submitting a form that was added dynamically to the page.

Comment: How about `$(document).on('submit', '#myform', function(e){ ... });`

Comment: @BrianGottier thought of that (should have put in OP) - also doing nothing

Comment: I always use `action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'`

Comment: I've never seen anyone put HTML directly inside a script tag. This really works for you in the past?

Comment: @BrianGottier Yeah HTML I want to put in the page but don't want to exist in the dom yet, rather than storing it in a js string var. I'm not 100% that I've done it with a form before though... not sure that should matter.

Comment: This will work for you `$("#myform").submit( function (ev) { });`

Comment: Someone posted that the IDs are duplicated and I would think that that does cause an issue, but @BrianGottier's answer does work https://jsfiddle.net/99sbj99a/

Comment: @j08691 the IDs are not duplicated - the HTML inside the script tag is treated as a string, and are not part of the DOM, so they aren't accessible and don't count

Comment: Using a script tag like that is not really a problem, but it's certainly not good form *(pun intended)*, and in my opinion a horrible way to hide the form temporarily.

Comment: I said I would think that it would cause a problem, not that it was causing a problem. And as you can see in the fiddle, using a delegated event handler works.

Comment: @adeneo This pattern is typically seen with client-side templating. I would tend to agree, but the way I have to get this into the page (a widget on a CMS page) it seemed the best option. I needed a way to hold my new HTML that would be added to an existing modal element on click.

Comment: @j08691 it DOES, but it's important to note that the reason it does is because the direct handler with the third parameter passed as `false` was blocking, and removing that fixes the root issue.

Comment: Sure, Knockout and Handlebars do this, and as I said, it's not a problem, but in my opinion, it's not a very good way to handle things like this, but again, there's nothing really wrong with it, other than it looks and smells bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that good with JQuery but removing the `false` param from the `on()` makes it work. Not sure what that param is supposed to do...

```js
document.getElementById("modal").innerHTML = document.getElementById("modalcontent").innerHTML;
console.log($("#myform").length); //<- confirms form element exists

$("#myform").on('submit', function (ev) {
    console.log("MADE IT jQuery!!") //<- but I never see this
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="modalcontent">
  <form id="myform" action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="whatever" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
</script>
<div id="modal"></div>
```

---

The reason this works is that `jQuery.on`, when used with 3 parameters in this fashion, assumes the third is the callback. It accepts `false` as the shorthand equivalent for

```
function(){
    return false;
}
```

which is why nothing at all happened, including delegated listeners picking up the event.

Answer (score -1):

In addition, submit is fired only on form element, that is why this code didn't work!

```html
//modal shows up just fine
$(document).on("submit", "#myform", function(){
    console.log("Delegated!") <- never see this
});
```

Comment: Incorrect. As this fiddle posted by @j08691 shows, delegated events work just fine: jsfiddle.net/99sbj99a  - the event fires on the form element, but does traverse the DOM.